# Physical back Button or slide doesnt go to previous page

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

Today i experienced a strange problem in my Flutter application. After installing the Firebase messaging and the Flutter local notifications packages, and made the adjustments on iOS and Android, i saw that the back button on emulator and on physical device and the slide back, didnt go to previous page, instead they were pushing the app to the background.

I tried almost everything i found on the web, like change the flutter channel or run some flutter clean etc. Nothing worked.

The FCM works correct

This is some code of my main.dart:

```
 Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Constants.pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And this is my FirebaseApi file:

```
Future<void> _handleBackgroundNotificationMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.notification != null) return;
  await   App.materialKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/appoinments');
}

 class FirebaseApi {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final _localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final _androidChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important   Notifications',
importance: Importance.high,
  );

  Future<void> initPushNotifications() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
    .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
    );
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(_handleMessage);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_handleBackgroundNotificationMessage);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  // final notification = message.notification;
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  // if (notification == null) return;
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    _localNotifications.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          _androidChannel.id,
          _androidChannel.name,
          channelDescription: _androidChannel.description,
          icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
          // other properties...
        ),
      ),
      payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
    );
  }
});
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message == null) return;

    App.materialKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/appoinments');
  }

  onClickNotification(payload) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> dat = json.decode(payload);
    // if (dat['type'] == 'appointment') {
    //   print('TRIED TO CALL UPDATE');
    // }
    App.materialKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/appoinments');
  }

  Future initLocalNotifications() async {
    const iOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);

await _localNotifications.initialize(
  settings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
      (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
    final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload!));
    _handleMessage(message);
    // onNotifications.add(payload as String?);
  },
);

final platform = _localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
    AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
await platform?.createNotificationChannel(_androidChannel);
// onNotifications.stream.listen(onClickNotification);
  }

  Future initNotifications() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
);
final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
print(fcmToken);
print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

initPushNotifications();
initLocalNotifications();
 }
}
```

Comment: some sample code would be nice. so we can help you more

Comment: Do you want to upload my Firebase initialisation code? The worst thing is I dont know what to upload. In iOS in release mode it works perfect, only on Android this happens

Comment: so when you start the app and press the back button, this is normal behavior to go in background. do you use Navigator.of?? where you push to another page but don't save it in the navigation history?

Comment: show anything where you navigate from first to second screen, or something like that

Comment: The application until yesterday was working fine. I have a global material key, and a separate file for navigators. Just give me a sec to upload some code. As I told above on iOS is working fine like it was working on Android too. I dont know what happened maybe its some configuration on build.grandle or something like this. Wait for my code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a temporary solution. The problem was with Android 13 gesture and the communication between Flutter framework, on which of them is gonna handle first the gestures. By default is ok but I added **FlutterFragmentActivity** in the MainActiviry.kt file for the FCM integration. **FlutterFragmentActivity** and **enableOnBackInvokedCallback:true** (in AndroidManifest) aren't working well together. So I added **false** as a temporary solution and it works.

Comment: After banging my head for a while with this, this was the exactly my case and the solution. 

Just to confirm, you just removed enableOnBackInvokedCallback from the manifest and you're waiting for flutter to catch up? Is there an issue that can be tracked?

Comment: I didnt remove. I just set it to false. Yes i wait flutter on how will respond to this native issue. I just saw my app not working correctly with phones button. So i had to do the research all alone cause every code i used didnt work

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and for taking the time to publish your original solution

Comment: You are welcome.. Everything to help the community

Comment: So this solution stopped working for me on the new flutter 3.16.0. Did you upgrade / are you seeing the same?

Comment: No i haven't yet. Thow the project i did went live, i ll try when i ll do some updates